# So you use cedar noise reduction and it helps but then where to

Tags: noise, reduction, cedar, izotope

So here's the thing , movie shot on location but somewhat noisy at times , crickets -birds- wind - . I used a combination of cedar noise reduction and izotope rx2 . I feel this combination yields great clean results . " ps I will note use cedar on a piece then rx it as well but cedar is great at something's rx2 is not and visa versa .. But inevitably I end up with a voice track that is clean but now has lost the natural resonance . In order for the noise reduction to be effective at taking out say crickets the reduction  % is general a bit more than say room ambience which leaves this horrible almost gated voice . I have revibe but my level of experience with reverb use is minimal , I opt for the safer option of not using than using reverb and killing the mix.

Any suggestions to bring the natural sound without making the voice sound like a bathroom experience.

Answer (score 9):

> But inevitably I end up with a voice track that is clean but now has lost the natural resonance

This is what dialogue mixers spend years, decades, perfecting - as well as dialogue editors, for their properly-prepared tracks make or break a dialogue mix.

In short, I recommend being more open and accepting of noise.  Used decisively an treated with respect, it can be your best friend.  Treated naively, it can be your worst nightmare.  Always leaving a small bit of noise is okay, and many times necessary to keep the dialogue 'alive'.  And sometimes adding noise can 'remove noise' psychoacoustically.  This part really depends upon how well a dialogue editor has prepared his/her tracks for you beforehand though.

Noise can actually be your ally if you are willing to allow its voice to be heard.

As for suggestions to bring the natural sound?  Just let the natural sound have an opportunity to breathe in the first place! ;)

Comment: Can't really say it better. I've spent years mixing dialogue and I have reached a place where I can accept a little noise and concentrate more on the quality of the voice.  The number one rule for me is keeping the track smooth.  If its smooth then the viewer/listener can live with a little noise.  The first thing I teach the newer guys on our crew is don't be too heavy handed with your noise reduction.